# simulation in COOJA is too slow

Tags: timer, contiki, cooja

I am using COOJA simulator to simulate an ad_hoc scenario which has 20 mobile mote and one static client. the type of the motes is exp5438. the client broadcast a message and all other motes who have received the message, set a timer for 10 seconds and rebroadcast the message after expiring their timer, whilst some motes who received the client's message, make new message and broadcast their own messages.
the speed of the simulation is too slow. I waited hours and hours but it seems some motes will never be able to receive a message.

I run the simulator in run_bigmem state and the speed has been improved a little, but not enough. I used stimer, etimer and rtimer. none of them made better performance. Is there any way which make a simulator to run faster?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Try Cooja motes instead of exp5438.

Comment: I need to use exp5438. all other types of motes stopped in the cause of "overflow ram". only exp5438 can handle the amuount of memory that I need.

Comment: Cooja motes have unlimited RAM.

Comment: I tried several times, but the simulator crashed and jumped out of the program every time. do I need any specific configuration to use this kind of mote?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Try Contiki-NG with the Docker image, it has improved Cooja mote implementation and many simulation files (in the tests for example) that can be used as examples.

Answer (score 0):

Run cooja in non-GUI node. This will make simulation run a bit faster. Moreover, you must run the cooja on better CPU like Intel Xeon to enhance simulation speed.

Start COOJA without GUI and run simulation in sim.csc

> java -mx512m -jar dist/cooja.jar -nogui=sim.csc

Comment: I tried this solution. I got this error when trying to use -nogui as a command : "Unrecognized option: -nogui / Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. / 
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit." I have no idea that what does this mean. do you knoe how to solve it?